# 2 executable in a method in java

Tags: java, android, methods

java noob here, I'm just wondering how to have 2 functions run in a single method? I have tried switch case but it doesn't do what I have in mind...

I want to include this 2 codes -

```
            detachThread();
        RFBThread persistentRfbThread = this.rfbThread;
        this.rfbThread = null;
        return persistentRfbThread;
```

and this-

```
if (_listeningDialog.isShowing() && _currentRecognizer != null)
        {
            // If a recognition is in progress, save it, because the activity
            // is about to be destroyed and recreated
            SavedState savedState = new SavedState();
            savedState.Recognizer = _currentRecognizer;
            savedState.DialogText = _listeningDialog.getText();
            savedState.DialogLevel = _listeningDialog.getLevel();
            savedState.DialogRecording = _listeningDialog.isRecording();
            savedState.Handler = _handler;

            _currentRecognizer = null; // Prevent onDestroy() from canceling
            return savedState;
        }
        return null;
```

in here-

```
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
```

}

what's a proper way to do it?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Can you generalize your problem? Are you trying to create two threads and wait until they finish?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the right term for it but is it possible to have them both executed under the public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() { ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Public Thread persistentRfbThread(){

    detachThread();
    RFBThread persistentRfbThread = this.rfbThread;
    this.rfbThread = null;
    return persistentRfbThread;
    }

and this-


       Public SavedState mystate(){
      if (_listeningDialog.isShowing() && _currentRecognizer != null)
    {
        // If a recognition is in progress, save it, because the activity
        // is about to be destroyed and recreated
        SavedState savedState = new SavedState();
        savedState.Recognizer = _currentRecognizer;
        savedState.DialogText = _listeningDialog.getText();
        savedState.DialogLevel = _listeningDialog.getLevel();
        savedState.DialogRecording = _listeningDialog.isRecording();
        savedState.Handler = _handler;

        _currentRecognizer = null; // Prevent onDestroy() from canceling
        return savedState;
    }
    return null;
    }
```

Call this two methods in here-

```
 public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {

//Define your condition when you require to have the data from these two function

 if(Condition 1 satisfies){

  Therad t = null;
   t = persistentRfbThread();
  }
else{
SavedState mystate;
 mystate = mystate();
  }
}
```